# How to use fonts for all pages in an android application app

Tags: android, css, fonts

I have applied vision.otf for assets/font and main/font in my project and set styles.xml as follows

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/vision</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/vision</item>
    </style>


    <style name="MyTextField" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:ems">10</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">textPersonName</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
         <item name="android:textColor">@color/lightGrey</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/lightGrey</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/lightGrey</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">start</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>

    </style>



</resources>
```

but the font style can't change at all when it comes to the execution. Would you please tell me how to override the font family without using object classes ?

Answer (score 1):

You could extend your application class and set the default font over there.

There is a great library for the same called [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) which will reduce a lot of your work in the application extended class and I have been using it since a long time.

You could just do this : 
Step 1 : Include the dependency

```
dependencies {
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
}
```

Step 2 : Installation

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                        .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-RobotoRegular.ttf")
                        .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                        .build()
        );
//....
}
```

This will set the font you choose to the entire application.As simple as that!

Suppose you need to change a specific view's font, you could do this :

```
<TextView
android:text="@string/hello_world"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"/>
```

Please go through the library once to check all the details such as how to organize your font assets etc, it's a really handy one

Hope it helps.